# How to optimize string comparison in basic python which uses +1 iteration?

Tags: python, string, optimization, iteration

I have the following two strings which have their own starting coordinates

```
string1='CADBDCXDCAXDDDAADXDADCC'
string2='AABCXXABACBBBDDXDCAAXB'
coordinate1=42
coordinate2=180
```

So, `string1` starts at 42, and `string2` starts at 180. These strings are only composed of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `X`.

The way to find the end coordinates between these strings requires us to skip the `X` characters. Here is my implementation, which is a for loop through each character, iterating by 1 if the character is not `X`.

```
def convert_coordinates(first_str, second_str, index1, index2):
    x = index1
    y = index2
    for char1, char2 in zip(first_str, second_str):
        if char1!='X':
            x+=1
        if char2!='X':
            y+=1
    return [x, y]
```

which when run, outputs the following:

```
convert_coordinates(string1, string2, coordinate1, coordinate2)
[61, 198]
```

My problem is, iterating this way feels like old C code, and I'm implementing this in Python. Therefore, I suspect this is very slow compared to other data structures. Is it possible to optimize this somehow, possibly using NumPy maybe? I would like to get away from basic python structures....

Comment: The number of non-X characters in a string can be more easily determined via `len(S) - S.count('X')`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"string1 starts at 42, and string2 starts at 180"*?

Comment: @Austin Each string has its own coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than counting in a very manual way like this, you can use a generator expression and the `sum()` built-in, i.e:

```
>>> sum(1 for c in string1 if c != "X")
20
```

Note that your use of `zip` in your example means the slightly longer first string is being cut off at the length of the shorter one, hence the different result (in your example code the last character of the first string is never counted). If this isn't a bug, you could just cut the strings down to the minimum of the two lengths.

Comment: I've never noticed this behavior of `zip()` before! Thank you. Apparently there's a function in `itertools` in order to zip together two lists of different lengths: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest